# Visual Studio 2013 New project creation error

Tags: visual-studio

I have done fresh installation of mircosoft visual studio 2013 ultimate but I am not been able to create a new project in visual studio . While Creating a project I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are installing Visual Studio in Windows 10 machine.
Please follow the link to solve the issue.

[Launching issues with Windows 10 and Visual Studio.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/launching-issues-with-windows-10-and-visual-studio/44cde506-4272-4ce7-a3ce-382e5cea04f6)

Comment: i have installed visual studio but I am not been able to start a project yes I do have installed visual studio in windows 10